# Fetch data from API with token result in [TypeError: Network request failed]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, backend, fetch-api

I just can't get it to work. I need to fetch a list of objects from an API. The method has to be GET and i have the token for Authorization header. this is the fetch function right now. I console logged the bearer const, and result in Bearer `<toke>`.

```
const fetchListChats = (accessToken) => {
    const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

    fetch('https://api.quickmatic.ai/api/chat/list', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 
        'Authorization': bearer,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log('Data:', data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

I tried a lot of things, but still not manage to make it work.

Comment: what is the response you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have postman you can try this api in post man and set Bearer  ,

then if you get response  in postman your code have a proplem

in postman you can get code and then copy in your code after code is work ,

you can refactor ,

and i think in headers :

`headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"}`

if you try this and dont be work , try your api in postman !

i hope this help

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is simple. The other developer i worked with write the wrong Endpoint in the documentation.